# Is there a website with options chain charts?

Tags: options, websites, chart

I would like to see a chart in the change of the bid price of an options chain. For example I'd like to see a daily chart of the bid price of ZNGA at a strike price of $10.

Is there a free website that shows this? Free is preferable of course :)

Answer (score 1):

http://dailyfinance.com

Enter a stock ticker, then click on the Chain link to the left.

Then, click on the option tickers to see their charts.

EDIT: the site has changed, and there are no more option charts.

So why are option charts so tough to find? Options are derivatives of the stock. Option prices are defined by a formula. The inputs are stock pricxe, strike, days to expiration, dividend, risk-free interest rate, and volatility. Volatility is the only thing that cannot be easily looked up.

With a Black-Scholes calculator, and some reasonable volatility selections, it's possible to make your own fairly accurate option chart. I don't think it's very enlightening, though. The interesting things are: the stock price movement (as always), and the nature of option pricing behavior in general (understanding how the formula represents crowd behavior).

Comment: Can you be more clear about what I click on when you say "option tickers"? Nothing I click on in the option chain table does anything...

Comment: The dailyfinance site has changed since I posted the answer 3.5 years ago.

Comment: ah... that's a shame.

Comment: Here's why you may not need option charting: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/13012/recommendation-on-options-back-testing-tool-please/13050#13050

Answer (score 0):

The other link no longer shows that and redirects to AOL website. You can find a chart like that here:
https://research.capitaloneinvesting.com/research/main/ETFs/Options?symbol=SPY

EDIT: Now this is dead too because I believe someone else (ETRADE) bought out Capital One.